# Will dual booting make a laptop slower?

Tags: dual-boot

Will dual booting make my laptop's performance speed slower than it was before? I have previously installed Ubuntu 14 in my desktop along with Windows 7. I thought it might be the reason for my pc to get slower. I am planning to install Ubuntu in my laptop so I am asking.

Comment: Ya dual boot is not going to affect your PC speed. If the issue is with a specific software check with their support for some tweaks. In case PC performs slow, try to remove unnecessary software and free some memory space.

Answer (score 0):

Dual booting would not make your computer slower theoritically.

A computer gets slow if too many processes run at the same time. It has mostly nothing to do with hard disk data.

Answer (score 0):

Actually, theoretically speaking, a dual boot installation has the potential to make a computer behave faster than it would if either booted installation commanded the entire hard drive alone.  The reason is that because in a dual boot involving only one hard drive, the heads only need to track half (or whatever fraction) as far.

Theories aside, in my experience the introduction of Linux only appears to slow a computer when the condition that led its owner to try Ubuntu in the first place, often a dying hard drive, continues to get worse.  Please check your drive health.